# Tensorflow: the number of produced checkpoint files doesn't match the configured inputs for model_main_tf2.py

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm using a pre-trained model in [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), for Object Detection, within CoLab (Tensorflow `v2.7.0`).

The (*new*) dataset consists of 255 images for training. The `train_config > batch_size` in `pipeline.config` is `8`. So I intend to make a checkpoint every one epoch (thus, `checkpoint_every_n`: 255/8= ~32), and will train in **100** epochs; thus, `num_train_steps` is `3200`. As a result, I *assume* there will be **100 checkpoint files** generated.

```
!python model_main_tf2.py \
  --pipeline_config_path="./models/pipeline.config" \
  --model_dir="./models" \
  --checkpoint_every_n=32 \
  --num_train_steps=3200 \
  --alsologtostderr
```

However, there are only **7** checkpoint files after the training. Here is the snapshot from the tool `tree /F` on Windows command line.

[image]

Did I miss something (e.g. an additional configuration somewhere)? Is my above assumption correct? Or this is simply a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In the file `model_main_tf2.py`, the main loop is:

```
with strategy.scope():
      model_lib_v2.train_loop(
          pipeline_config_path=FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
          model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
          train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
          use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
          checkpoint_every_n=FLAGS.checkpoint_every_n,
          record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
```

Checking `model_lib_v2.train_loop()` ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py)), there is a default argument:

```
def train_loop(
    pipeline_config_path,
    model_dir,
    config_override=None,
    train_steps=None,
    use_tpu=False,
    save_final_config=False,
    checkpoint_every_n=1000,
    checkpoint_max_to_keep=7, # Here!
    record_summaries=True,
```

That reasons why there are **only 7 Checkpoint files generated**. They should be the last ones.

In addition, the argument `checkpoint_every_n` is **not strictly** respected. It is affected by `NUM_STEPS_PER_ITERATION`, which is hardcoded with `100` (can't be changed from outsite). In file `model_lib_v2.py`, function `train_loop()`, [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py#L711):

```
if ((int(global_step.value()) - checkpointed_step) >=
              checkpoint_every_n):
    manager.save() # Here!
    checkpointed_step = int(global_step.value())
```

...meaning: In every iteration, it moves 100 steps, and I indicated `num_train_steps` as `3200`; so the Checkpoint should be made for every 100 steps, ending up 32 files. Plus one Checkpoint file at the very beginning ([line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/812ab923b2a52458ecb6b336f10b84634c91fe52/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py#L675)), we end up with `ckpt-33` as showed.